# Can Notepad ++ display a file's section/subsection document structure?

Tags: notepad++, latex

As we all know, Notepad ++ is the perfect program. That is, except for one thing--as far as I can tell, there is no plugin or native function that will display your file's document structure in outline form. I have searched high and low for this and I'm asking here as a last effort.

Specifically I would like to be able to visualize a .tex file, with the various `\section`, `\subsection`, and `\subsubsection` branches in an outline. It would also be useful for seeing the structure of other coded documents, like .html files.

Does anyone know of any way to do this? I know that some other programs, like TexStudio, have this ability, but one can only pay so high a price.

Answer (score 2):

#### Code folding

Notepad++ has [code folding](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Lines_And_Blocks#Code_folding) built in:

> **Code folding**
>
> Most programming languages support the notion of code block. When
> Notepad++ detects a keyword or operator that starts a block, it
> inserts a fold point, which shows on the fold margin.
>
> You can click on such a symbol to fold/unfold the corresponding block.
> Its first line is always displayed. Ctrl-clicking a folded point will
> recursively unfold all blocks inside it.
>
> Additionally, the View menu provides the following commands:
>
> - Fold all blocks (Alt-0)
> - Unfold all blocks (Alt+Shft+0)
> - Fold this block (Ctrl+Alt+F)
> - Unfold this block (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F)
> - Fold this block at level n (Alt+n)
> - Unfold this block at level n (Alt+Shift+n)
>
> The words "fold" and "collapse" are used interchangeably, and
> similarly "unfold" and "uncollapse".
>
> Topmost code blocks are said to be at level 1. Their direct sub-blocks
> are at level 2 and so on. The block level must be a digit between 1
> and 8. The default shortcuts use the top keyboard row, not the numeric
> keypad. Note that the folding block where the current line lies is
> highlighted on the fold margin. You can change the colour being used
> using Settings -> Styler Configurator -> Global Styles , Fold active.
> This will work with the box or circle folding block style only.
>
> The shortcuts for folding and unfolding a level have the same
> appearance on the Shortcut mapper. However, collapsing commands follow
> Collapse current level, and likewise for uncollapsing.
>
> Fold state for a document is recorded in session files so as to be
> restored on reopening the document from the session.

Source [Lines And Blocks](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Lines_And_Blocks#Code_folding)

---

#### I would like to be able to visualize a .tex file in an outline

You will need to add Tex as a [User Defined Language](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/User_Defined_Languages).

The easiest way to do this is to import a pre-built Tex UDL file.

There is one available at [LaTeX Editing Using Notepad++](http://johnbruer.com/2013/05/21/latex-editing-using-notepad/):

> Notepad++ is built on the Scintilla text-editing library, which
> includes support for highlighting TeX files. I preferred to make some
> changes to the style, and unfortunately this requires you to create a
> user-defined language. The user interface to do this in Notepad++ is
> under Language > Define your language.... Here you can specify your
> own options and export them to a UDL (User Defined Language) XML file.
> If you wish, you can import [my UDL file](https://johnbruer.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/tex_udl.xml) for TeX and modify it to suit
> your needs.8 To force Notepad++ to use your user-defined language when
> opening TeX files, disable the built-in TeX processor by going to
> Settings > Preferences... > Language Menu/Tab Settings and moving TeX
> from the Available items list to the Disabled items list.
>
> Note that by default you will not have auto-complete available for a
> user-defined language. In order to correct this, you can copy the
> `tex.xml` file from your Notepad++ install (on my machine this is
> `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\APIs\tex.xml`) to a file
> named `userDefineLang.xml` in your settings folder (on my machine
> `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\plugins\APIs\userDefineLang.xml`).
> This is somewhat inelegant as the same auto-completion list must be
> used for all user-defined languages. Notepad++ is not perfect.

---

#### Examples showing a `.tex` file folded and unfolded.

[image]

[image]

---

#### It would also be useful for seeing the structure of other documents, like .html

That is built in. See Folding above.